# Why some servers return different content-length for the same file?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, download, content-length

I'am developing an Android DownloadManager app and I've faced with a condition on which some servers like Linkedin server send different `content-length` on their response header for the same file. For example consider the link below which represents an image on the Linkedin:

```
https://media-exp1.licdn.com/dms/image/C5622AQH-gfIVQhjzUw/feedshare-shrink_2048_1536/0/1615695432381?e=1619049600&v=beta&t=-zbenzxOleARjnxVRMlsX-_6gmlvhzU0-2M-peUHLyI
```

When I send an HEAD request(using POSTMAN) to get the image's information, sometimes `Content-Length` is `77241` and sometimes is `79191`. I know that the actual size of the image is `79191` bytes but I don't know why it sends `77241` in most cases.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure how likely this is, but it's possible you're seeing the effects of dynamic image optimization where the content is taking a slightly different path to you.

Comment: Is the `Content-encoding` the same?

Comment: @user207421 Yes. It is the same.

Comment: I used two browsers, Postman and a simple Android App to download the picture and the results were the same: Content-length: 76845

Comment: @emandt That's wrong content-length. The picture's server sends different content-length sometimes. Open the link above in a browser and drag and drop it to your desktop, you will see that its size is 79191 bytes.

Comment: The problem is the Server. Now I just tried again and the answered Header is completly different then before. Now I get 79191. I just tried many times and I get always 79191.

Comment: @emandt Yeah. It is changed sometimes. I posted the way that I could get the right file size. Please look that that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know that how this was happening but the problem was solved(atleast until now) by using another strategy to get the size of the file.

What I used to do was to send a `HEAD` request to server and read its `Content-Length`. But as I mentioned the `content-length` sent was wrong sometimes. So I sent a `GET` request with the `Range` header equal to `0-255` and I checked that if `Content-Range` header is present in the the response headers or not. If it is present, I extracted the file size from it because its value's format is like this: `bytes 0-255/79191` and `79191` is the correct file size.

If `Content-Range` is not present, I send a HEAD request without `Range` header and get the file size from `Content-Length` header. I think in this way the file size is much reliable. Am I wrong?

Comment: There isn't any valid reason to think that the HEAD answer is always right and fixed. Yestarday I done many GETs like today but answers were completly different than now....so even the HEAD answer could change in time.

Comment: @emandt My first strategy is a GET request which mentioned above. I examined an Android app which showed me the correct file size and It was extracting the file size in that way, so I decided to extract the size as that app was doing.

Comment: I hope for you the behaviour don't change in the future ;) Good luck